# Knowing which process produced a sound

Tags: process, operating-system, audio

My computer often produces a "ding" sound, and I can't associate it with anything.  Is it possible to programmatically determine the source of the beeps?  For example can I hook the sound driver?  If so, can you point out some examples or references?

Comment: To whoever closed this: This may be "not a programming question" but it may require a programming solution. I think it relevant.

Comment: Why was this closed? I'd love to know the answer.

Comment: Reopened.  It looks like a programming question to me and I  (as well as others) are curious about solutions.

Comment: Tim, the person who close it first is Jeff Atwood THE administrator of this website. Keep it close.

Comment: Daok - Jeff said on SO podcast that the site should police itself though.

Comment: Daok, Why should I care what Jeff thinks?  The bottom line is that I, and others, think it is a perfectly valid question.  It sure looks like one to me.  I challenge you to convince me otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately Jeff's "answer" is not a programmatic answer.  I'm with theman on this.

Answer (score 2):

Omer, this isn't a programming question, despite your edit.

No programming is necessary. Close applications one by one over time until the ding stops.

Comment: I don't want to get into your fight, but since I write monitoring programs as part of my research, I would actually love to know of a programmatic way to know where sounds are coming from and also where sound input is routing to.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system is this?  If you're on Linux, you can use the [`lsof(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) command to see what files every process has open.  If a process is playing sound, it will have the sound device file open, so you can grep for it like so:

```
lsof | grep -E '/dev/(snd|dsp)'
```

Another option is to use [`fuser(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser), which works similarly to `lsof`.